# How to determine iOS Simulator or Android Simulator using Robot Framework

Tags: appium, robotframework

I am looking for a way to write scripts on Robot Framework so that I can run same set of scripts for iOS and Android. I understand that Android and iOS has different arguments for appium on Robot Framework (Also, device name, appPackage etc will be different). How can I write some if/else condition so that I can determine if the simulator is Android then run 'xyz' keywords but if the simulator is iOS then run 'abcd' keywords?

For example:

```
***Test Case***  
Run Keyword if  .....   Platform is Android ......  Login for Android  
Run Keyword if .....    Platform is iOS .......     Login for iOS

**Keywords**  
Login for Android  
xyz  

Login for iOS   
abcd
```

In this case, how should I determine if "Platform is Android" or "Platform is iOS"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best solution would be probably to have ${platform} global variable that would determine platform on a test level.
And also you place keyword names from a variable, that means following:

```
Run Keyword If    '${platform}'=='${global_androidPlatform}'    ${keywordName}
```

But I'm pretty sure there is better solution somewhere to be honest. :)